# color in xaml from c#(windows phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone

XAML:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
```

C#:

```
public class colors
{
    public string Gray
    {
        set {}
        get{ return "#FF22262a";}
    }
}
```

There is no error when I compile. But rectangle does not fill in "#FF22262a"

EDIT:
This code does not work too:
MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyGray2}"></TextBlock>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public String MyGray2
{
    set { }
    get { return "gjnuegheugheog"; }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="FlagLib.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FlagLib"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
            <vm:colors x:Key="vmColors"  />
...
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Tap="onToggleHorizontal" DataContext="{StaticResource vmColors}">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
...
```

EDIT3:
MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="proba5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:proba5" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <vm:colors x:Key="vmColors"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">


        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmColors}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

colors.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace proba5
{
    public class colors
    {
        public string Gray
        {
            set { }
            get { return "#FF22262a"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Why i got 
**The name "colors" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:proba5".**

Comment: does it work when you write `Fill="FF22262a"`? Do you get any binding errors?

Comment: It work with `Fill="#FF22262a"`

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in the debug output window? Did you set your `DataContext`?

Comment: as a sidenote, I would probably put `colors` in a `ResourceDictionary` as a  `StaticResource` and keep it in xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `DataContext`.

```
public MyPage()
{
   DataContext = new colors();
}
```

I prefer to do it in XAML.

Import your namespace at the top

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

Add the class as a resource (you can do this at app level if you prefer)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <vm:colors x:Key="vmColors"  />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Assign to the DataContext (in this case I've assigned it to the Grid so any control within the Grid will assume the `vmColors` DataContext, unless you change it for that particular child control).

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmColors}">
   <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
</Grid>
```

Here's the full XAML for a page so you can see where the code goes.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MyClass.MyPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" // << IMPORT NAMESPACE
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    //ALLOW THE CLASS TO BE ACCESSED VIA STATICRESOURCE
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <vm:colors x:Key="vmColors"/> 
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">      

        //SET THE DATACONTEXT OF THE GRID TO THE COLORS CLASS
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmColors}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Gray}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Your binding needs a DataContext otherwise it doesn't know where to bind from (how does it know where your "Gray" property is?). So you want to tell it, "look inside my `colors` class for any binding calls I make". You can either do that in the code-behind of your `Page` (e.g. MainPage.xaml) or in the actual XAML itself. That's what the `DataContext` property essentially does.

Comment: Was updating answer as you typed :)

Comment: you could also do `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext><vm:colors /></...>` and skip the `DataContext=""` in the `Grid`

Comment: @Default Yup, that's just as valid. I purposely did it this way so that OP can see the use of `StaticResource` for other purposes but your suggestion is good.

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov - You've used `MyGray` in your XAML but the property is called `Gray`.

Comment: corrected but still not work. Can you show your C# code. I will try to compile your example

Comment: Is your `colors` class definitely in the `FlagLib` namespace?

Comment: Yes. It project name.

Comment: Not sure what it could be. I've just created a test app with my code and it works fine. If you use `<Rectangle Fill="Gray" />` (without any binding) can you see the rectangle?

Comment: Yes with `<Rectangle Fill="Gray" />` it's work. Can you send me your test app?

Comment: My code above is the test app. The class is just your class from your question.

Comment: I have a lot of errors when create new project. Can you write c# code and project name?

Comment: Sorry I can't give you any more help, someone else might be able to. I don't know what errors you're getting. The XAML above was pasted into a new project, the namespaces changed to match the new project namespace, and your `colors` class was copy/pasted into a new class (that's the only C# code). The project runs fine with a gray rectangle (or whatever code was used in the colors class).

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov - Did you actually build and run the app? I copy/pasted your edit, changed the namespaces to `proba5` and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. What you're trying to is implicitly cast a `string` into a `Color`, which is not possible. You should better considering this code :

```
public SolidColorBrush MyGray
{
    set { }
    get { return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(172, 172, 172, 0)); }
}
```

Here is my source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill.aspx

There are other ways to manage color in XAML, you could browse msdn for more information.

**Edit :** It's normal that you have no error on compilation. XAML is interpreted at execution.

**Edit 2 :** Update the code.

Comment: Have you browsed that link I just showed you ? I updated my answer in order to be more explicit for you.

Comment: now i got error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'**

Comment: the return value should probably be `Brush` and not `Color`

Comment: There's a built in converter that will convert a string to the brush. There's no need to change OP's code.